# How to merge tree in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

Let's say I have a database with named nodes and that the database is either empty or has the following content:

[image]

I now need a neo4j statement, that inserts exactly that tree structure, if it does not exists already in the database.

For simple node pair merge, I could use something like

```
MERGE ({name: 'A'})-[:R1]->({name: 'B'})
```

But I want the tree structure. How do I add `C` here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to add a label on your tree node (`Tree` in my above example) and create a unique constraint on the name attribute like this :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Tree) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE;
```

Then you can use this script to create the `C` node and the others is they don't exist :

```
MERGE (a:Tree {name: 'A'})
MERGE (b:Tree {name: 'B'})
MERGE (c:Tree {name: 'C'})
MERGE (a)-[:R1]->(b)
MERGE (a)-[:R2]->(c);
```

As you can see you have to use one `MERGE` per node, and then one `MERGE` per relationship.